# Failed to read credentials from file

Tags: node.js, firebase

I wish to save the data in my firestore database, but I have a problem with my credentials. Every time I add environment variable of google and I deploy I get:

> Failed to read credentials from file "C:\procducthuntbackend-b58bd994f180.json": Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '"C:\procducthuntbackend-b58bd994f180.json"'

I make it

```
set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="C:\procducthuntbackend-b58bd994f180.json"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  My guess is that the file you specified doesn't exist (or isn't readable), given the error message.  Possibly it is misspelled (e.g. did you mean producthuntbackend?).

Comment: What command do you run to get that error? (Please add that information to your question, and not in a comment)

Comment: What do you mean by deploy?

Comment: Frank van Puffelen I run with this command firebase serve

Comment: Robert Moskal I mean by depoy here the update of the project on the firebase server